# Get the row in an excel.range where the Value is the same

Tags: c#, excel, linq

I am on a project in C # for excel and I try to recover the rows where the values ​​are identical :

- A
- B
- A

so i get the row 1 and the row 2
I already tried that :

```
Excel.Range xl = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range("Q2:Q" + lastRowOfTheSheet);
 var all = xl.Rows.Cast<Excel.Range>().Select(x => x.Value2.ToString()).ToList();
 var theRowsSameValue = xl.Rows.Cast<Excel.Range>().Where(y => y.Value2 != ?????????).Select(x => x.Row).ToList();
```

but i don't know what to put in the "Where". Someone have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get all the rows where the value is "A"? Or all the rows where the value is the same as the top row? Or would you like a list of groups of rows which have matching values?

Comment: I want all the rows where the value is A and if B is present twice i also want B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is going to be to group the rows, then check the count of each group then to 'ungroup' the rows again using the `.SelectMany` method. See below:

```
Excel.Range xl = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range("Q2:Q" + lastRowOfTheSheet);
 var theRowsSameValue = xl.Rows.Cast<Excel.Range>().GroupBy(y => y.Value2).Where(y => y.Count()>1).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Reading the method calls from left to right we **Group** by the value, then we **filter** for groups with more than 1 record (values that appear more than once), then we **flatten** the list of groups back into a list of cells.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i have this issue for groupBy : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range' does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' and no 'GroupBy' extension method that accepts a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range' n ' was found (a using directive or an assembly reference is missing?)....

Comment: apologies, I missed out the `.Rows.Cast` that you did in your snippet. See my edited answer.

Comment: Nice ! Thank you very much